# Python -- Pygame AttributeError: int object has no attribute 'draw'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, pygame, attributeerror

I want to call the `draw` and `move` methods for each item of `my_list`. I tried `my_objects.draw()` and `my_objects.move()` instead of `i.draw()` and `i.move()`, but I always get the same error. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 700)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, 500)
        self.height = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.width = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

my_list = []

for number in range(10):
    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_list.append(my_object)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))  
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        number.draw()
        number.move()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 53, in <module>
  number.draw()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

Comment: Check your indentation please but I seems that `number` is created when you do `for number in range` and this explains the error as number is an int by doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating through indexes. But you really want to iterate through items. So you don't need `range(len(...))` construction. Instead use `for item in items`. Try this:

```
for rect in my_list:
    rect.draw()
    rect.move()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! This mean I didn't need range(len(my_list))?

Comment: @Miray If you iterate over a `range`, the elements it gives you will be a number in that range, and numbers don't have draw methods. If you iterate over `my_list` itself, you'll get each element of `my_list`, which presumably do have draw methods.